# solve non-linear system of equations

Tags: equation-solving

I have a system of equations and I want to solve it to get x, y

$$\begin{cases} u= C_{1}+(x-C_{1})(1+k_{1}((x-C_{1})(x-C_{1})+(y-C_{2})(y-C_{2}))) \\ \\ v= C_{2}+(y-C_{2})(1+k_{2}((x-C_{1})(x-C_{1})+(y-C_{2})(y-C_{2}))) \end{cases}$$

If it possible I want to know how can it can be done in C++ too.

Update:
`Solve[]` gives me very large output, so the problem is that I want to place solution in my C++ aplication and $C_1$, $C_2$, $k_1$, $k_2$ are variables.
`CForm[]` doesn't help, I need more simple and suitable form for C++ to use.

Comment: You've tried `Solve[]`?

Comment: @J.M. yes, I tried `Solve` but it gives me large and not optimised output,I want to place output in my c++ aplication, even using `CForm` not help, how to better optimise it?

Comment: @mrgloom The solution you get with `Solve` is almost useless. If you substitute parameters for certain values you'll get more useful results, e.g. `Solve[{eq1, eq2} /. {C1 -> 1, C2 -> -1, k1 -> 1, k2 -> 1, u -> 3, 
   v -> 0}, {x, y}]`

Comment: ...and you've tried `FullSimplify[]` as well?

Comment: @J.M. seems looks better with `FullSimplify[]`,another question is how to get rid of `Slot` functions in output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without further assumptions of your used constants the solution is quite lengthy

```
eqs = {
  u == c1 + (x - c1) (1 + 
       k1 ((x - c1) (x - c1) + (y - c2) (y - c2))),
  v == c2 + (y - c2) (1 + k2 ((x - c1) (x - c1) + (y - c2) (y - c2)))
  };
Reduce[eqs, {x, y}]
```

If you can provide numerical values for your constants $C_n$ and $k_n$ it is probably possible to shorten the solution.

Please have a look on your system and notice, how the number of possible (real) solutions varies when the variables change

```
Manipulate[
 ContourPlot[{u == 
    c1 + (x - c1) (1 + k1 ((x - c1) (x - c1) + (y - c2) (y - c2))), 
   v == c2 + (y - c2) (1 + 
        k2 ((x - c1) (x - c1) + (y - c2) (y - c2)))}, {x, -5, 
   5}, {y, -5, 5}, PlotPoints -> ControlActive[10, 40], 
  MaxRecursion -> ControlActive[1, 5]],
 {u, -1, 1},
 {v, -1, 1},
 {c1, -1, 1},
 {c2, -1, 1},
 {k1, -1, 1},
 {k2, -1, 1}
]
```

[image]

Addionally, lets investigate in the first solution you get from the `Reduce` call

```
k1 == 0 && x == u && k2 != 0 && 
(y == Root[(-c1^2)*c2*k2 - c2^3*k2 + 2*c1*c2*k2*u - c2*k2*u^2 - v + 
   (1 + c1^2*k2 + 3*c2^2*k2 - 2*c1*k2*u + k2*u^2)*#1 - 3*c2*k2*#1^2 + k2*#1^3 & ,1] || 
 y == Root[(-c1^2)*c2*k2 - c2^3*k2 + 2*c1*c2*k2*u - c2*k2*u^2 - v + 
   (1 + c1^2*k2 + 3*c2^2*k2 - 2*c1*k2*u + k2*u^2)*#1 - 3*c2*k2*#1^2 + k2*#1^3 & ,2] || 
 y == Root[(-c1^2)*c2*k2 - c2^3*k2 + 2*c1*c2*k2*u - c2*k2*u^2 - v + 
   (1 + c1^2*k2 + 3*c2^2*k2 - 2*c1*k2*u + k2*u^2)*#1 - 3*c2*k2*#1^2 + k2*#1^3 & ,3])
```

What I want to show you is that you can hack the output of `Reduce` directly into C++. The  only thing you need is a `if/else` way through all the possible forms your solution can have.

Looking at the output above, you see that when `k1==0` and `k2!=0` your solution is that `x=u` and `y` can take 3 values. These three values are the roots of a polynomial of third order. Therefore, your three points are `{x,y1}, {x,y2}, {x,y3}`. Using the `Manipulate` and set `k1` to zero shows, that this is correct:

[image]

The points where the red and the blue lines cross have indeed the same `x` and 3 different `y`.

Therefore, the only thing required for your C++ code are basic arithmetic operations and a root-solver for polynomials of third order.

Comment: the problem is that I want to place solution in my c++ aplication and c1,c2,k1,k2 are variables.

Comment: @mrgloom, see my update.

Comment: how to format output to test each solution? (output very large and it's very complicated task to understand it)
how to remove complex solutions(x,y can be just usual numbers)?
how to add some known restrictions for example c1>0,c2>0?