# How to solve a system of non-linear equations with known constants and unknown constants?

Tags: equation-solving

I review these questions [Q1](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/86769/solve-a-system-of-non-linear-equations) and [Q2](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/9180/solve-non-linear-system-of-equations).

I wrote the following codes:

```
DEL = (1/2258332876800)*(80080*Subscript[c, 1]^6*Subscript[d, 1]^2 - 112*Subscript[c, 1]^5*Subscript[d, 1]*
     (-147900 + 46189*Subscript[d, 1] + 2145*Subscript[d, 1]^2 + 9724*Subscript[d, 2]) + 
    4*Subscript[c, 1]^4*(2246244*Subscript[d, 1]^3 + 45045*Subscript[d, 1]^4 - 1547*Subscript[d, 1]^2*
       (-10995 + 352*Subscript[c, 2] - 528*Subscript[d, 2]) + 23800*Subscript[d, 1]*(-6617 + 693*Subscript[d, 2]) + 
      272*(1147861 - 111930*Subscript[d, 2] + 3465*Subscript[d, 2]^2)) - 
    68*Subscript[c, 1]^3*(27027*Subscript[d, 1]^4 - 840*Subscript[d, 1]^2*(-1261 + 1452*Subscript[c, 2] - 1881*Subscript[d, 2]) + 
      Subscript[d, 1]^3*(765135 - 48048*Subscript[c, 2] + 36036*Subscript[d, 2]) + 
      9984*(18513 - 6160*Subscript[d, 2] + 315*Subscript[d, 2]^2) - 16*Subscript[d, 1]*(2024737 - 876330*Subscript[d, 2] - 
        10395*Subscript[d, 2]^2 + 280*Subscript[c, 2]*(-884 + 99*Subscript[d, 2]))) + 
    1400256*(336*(27*Subscript[d, 1]^2 + 24*Subscript[d, 1]*(5 + 3*Subscript[d, 2]) + 
        16*(15 + 10*Subscript[d, 2] + 3*Subscript[d, 2]^2)) - 24*Subscript[c, 2]*(135*Subscript[d, 1]^2 + 
        24*Subscript[d, 1]*(-14 + 15*Subscript[d, 2]) + 16*(-175 - 28*Subscript[d, 2] + 15*Subscript[d, 2]^2)) + 
      Subscript[c, 2]^2*(315*Subscript[d, 1]^2 + 24*Subscript[d, 1]*(-81 + 35*Subscript[d, 2]) + 
        16*(903 - 162*Subscript[d, 2] + 35*Subscript[d, 2]^2))) + 17*Subscript[c, 1]^2*(887040*Subscript[c, 2]^2*Subscript[d, 1]^2 + 
      280665*Subscript[d, 1]^4 + 68040*Subscript[d, 1]^3*(117 + 11*Subscript[d, 2]) + 
      6150144*(603 - 234*Subscript[d, 2] + 35*Subscript[d, 2]^2) + 139776*Subscript[d, 1]*(-693 + 1430*Subscript[d, 2] + 
        135*Subscript[d, 2]^2) + 16*Subscript[d, 1]^2*(6961669 + 1547910*Subscript[d, 2] + 31185*Subscript[d, 2]^2) - 
      96*Subscript[c, 2]*(20790*Subscript[d, 1]^3 + 35*Subscript[d, 1]^2*(7709 + 792*Subscript[d, 2]) + 
        520*Subscript[d, 1]*(-3784 + 1197*Subscript[d, 2]) + 208*(18513 - 6160*Subscript[d, 2] + 315*Subscript[d, 2]^2))) - 
    10608*Subscript[c, 1]*(80*Subscript[c, 2]^2*Subscript[d, 1]*(-484 + 189*Subscript[d, 1] + 252*Subscript[d, 2]) + 
      132*(315*Subscript[d, 1]^3 + 24*Subscript[d, 1]^2*(57 + 35*Subscript[d, 2]) + 
        768*(-175 - 28*Subscript[d, 2] + 15*Subscript[d, 2]^2) + 16*Subscript[d, 1]*(-1869 + 654*Subscript[d, 2] + 
          35*Subscript[d, 2]^2)) - Subscript[c, 2]*(8505*Subscript[d, 1]^3 + 840*Subscript[d, 1]^2*(110 + 27*Subscript[d, 2]) + 
        8448*(903 - 162*Subscript[d, 2] + 35*Subscript[d, 2]^2) + 16*Subscript[d, 1]*(-14949 + 21560*Subscript[d, 2] + 
          945*Subscript[d, 2]^2))))
```

I want to solve the following system equations which `Subscript[c, 1],Subscript[c, 2` are unknown variables and `Subscript[d, 1],Subscript[d, 2` are known variables:

```
E1 = D[DEL, {Subscript[c, 1], 1}]; 
E2 = D[DEL, {Subscript[c, 2], 1}]; 
Solve[E1 == 0 && E2 == 0, {Subscript[c, 1], Subscript[c, 2]}, Reals]
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: So, what are the specific values for `d1` and `d2`?

Comment: @MMM `Subscript[d, 1]` and `Subscript[d, 2]` are constant. Here we want to have Subscript[c, 1] and Subscript[c, 2] in terms of Subscript[d, 1] and Subscript[d, 2].

Comment: It will likely be easier to solve unrestricted (no domain restriction), then extract real solutions for given values of the parameters. Another possibility is to solve only when parameter values are given, using `NSolve`. This will allow to avoid costly symbolic computations involving `Root` objects.

Comment: I think that I need to a code similar `With[Constants -> {Subscript[d, 1], Subscript[d, 2]}, 
 NSolve[E1 == 0 && E2 == 0 , {Subscript[c, 1], Subscript[c, 2]}, 
  Reals]]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wanted to inform the system that Subscript[d,1] and Subscript[d,2] were constants. I was unable to do that because, for example, Subscript[d,1] is not a symbol (one often runs into problems trying to use subscripted symbols in Mathematica).

So I modified your definition of `DEL` and replace all subscripted variables with a non-subscripted version.

Using your definition of `DEL` (not repeated here).

```
DEL = DEL /. Subscript[a_, i_] :> ToExpression[ToString[a] ~~ ToString[i]]

SetAttributes[d1, Constant]
SetAttributes[d2, Constant]
```

Then proceed as in your query using Daniel Lichtblau's tip about not constraining the result to reals.

```
E1 = D[DEL, {c1, 1}];
E2 = D[DEL, {c2, 1}];
```

Now `Solve` produces a result (it is verbose, but at least I get a result)

```
Solve[E1 == 0 && E2 == 0, {c1, c2}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

In the result on my system there were nine solutions.

I copied the first solution (again, very verbose) and created the functions

```
c1[d1_, d2_] := N["copy of solution for c1"]
c2[d1_, d2_] := N["copy of solution for c2"]
```

Then I could, for example, plot `c1[x,y]` in a 3D plot

```
Plot3D[c1[x, y], {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The second function was slow so I made a table of values and used `ListPlot3D`.

```
table = Flatten[Table[{x, y, c2[x, y]}, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}], 
   1];

ListPlot3D[table]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Many many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to find numerical solution using `FindRoot` by fixing `d1` and `d2`.

```
Subscript[d, 2] = 1; Subscript[d, 1] = 1;
Plot3D[{E1, E2}, {Subscript[c, 1], -10, 10}, {Subscript[c, 2], -10,10}]
```

[image]

```
ContourPlot[{E1, E2}, {Subscript[c, 1], -5, 5}, {Subscript[c, 2], -12,12}]
```

[image]

```
Reap[FindRoot[{E1 == 0 && E2 == 0}, {{Subscript[c, 1], 4}, {Subscript[c, 2], 4}}, 
  StepMonitor :> Sow[{Subscript[c, 1], Subscript[c, 2]}]]]
```

> {{Subscript[c, 1] -> 4.01292, 
>     Subscript[c, 
>      2] -> -9.97329}, {{{3.32569, -9.05764}, {4.33577, -10.5018}, \
>   {4.05056, -10.032}, {4.01351, -9.97422}, {4.01292, -9.97329}, \
>   {4.01292, -9.97329}, {4.01292, -9.97329}}}}

Comment: I want to have `Subscript[c, 1]` and `Subscript[c, 2]` in terms of  `Subscript[d, 1]` and `Subscript[d, 2]` .